# Why there are no periodically poled BBO crystals?

Tags: non-linear-optics

I am researching the topic of quasi-phase matching and I was wondering why it is not possible to periodically pole beta barium borate crystal? (I haven't seen any papers on this topic at least)

Thanks!

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

Beta barium borate does not appear to be ferroelectric, based on a bit of searching.  So it can't be poled in the normal way.  However, it is birefringent, and likely could be grown under controlled conditions to obtain layers with alternating crystal orientations and a given layer spacing.